# ASP.Net Core MVC - Custom validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, ef-code-first, code-first

I am working with Code First on asp.net and I have the following class:

```
public class Producto
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ProductoId { get; set; }
    [Remote(action: "VerifySku", controller: "Producto", ErrorMessage = "El sku ya está asignado a un producto")]
    [DisplayName("SKU")]
    public string Sku { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Seleccione categoría")]
    [DisplayName("Categoria")]
    public Guid SubCategoriaProductoId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Categoria")]
    public SubCategoriaProducto SubCategoriaProducto { get; set; }
    public string Marca { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ingrese nombre")]
    [Remote(action: "VerifyName", controller: "Producto", ErrorMessage = "El producto ya existe")]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Detalle { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ingrese precio")]
    public int Precio { get; set; }
    public bool PorEncargo { get; set; }
    [Remote(action: "VerifyStock", controller: "Producto", AdditionalFields = nameof(PorEncargo))]
    public int Stock { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(1)]
    public int EstaActivo { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ImagenProducto> Imagenes { get; set; }
}
```

What I need is to add a custom validation, in which you must **Require stock** as long as the **PorEncargo** field is false.
I have not found anything how to do it in ASP.Net Core.

Answer (score 0):

> What I need is to add a custom validation, in which you must Require stock as long as the PorEncargo field is false.

```
public int Stock { get; set; }
```

From [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#required-attribute), you could find that *the validation system in .NET Core 3.0 and later treats non-nullable parameters or bound properties as if they had a `[Required]` attribute.*

Normally, we valid if the input of a `int` type property (such as `Stock`) is greater than 0, rather than `null`.